# Freetextbox Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to use firefox but my [freetextbox](http://freetextbox.com/) didn't work. However, when I use IE6 it works properly. I tried to use google chrome and an updated version of IE and it's also working. Has anyone else had this problem? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me in Chrome and FireFox. If you load up the [demo](http://freetextbox.com/demos/) on your machine using Firefox, IE (not 6) and Chrome does it work properly? If so, you need to check and make sure you've implemented it properly.

Comment: I see. I used validationgroup for my freetextbox. I tried to input values in my freetextbox and save in SQL server. And then, it keeps blocking me telling that i didn't input anything in my freetextbox.

Comment: So it isn't an issue with freetextbox it is a problem with _your_ implementation of validationgroup. Take a look at that and see if you can resolve the issue.